# listoffigures entry with page range?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

One of the "figues" I have in my document is in fact a sequence of figures ranging over several pages. The individual image shall not have captions in place (nor shall the image seqience as a whole), but I would like this to appear in the `\listoffigures` with the range, i.e., if `\pageref{first}` and `\pageref{last}` evaluate to 50 and 53, say, I want something like this to appear in the lof:

**Fig. 5.** My image sequence  . . . .  50-53

I managed to *almost* solve this with

```
\captionlistentry[figure]{My image sequence}
```

However, the problem with the page *range* still remains. Is there anything short of hardcoding my own writefile line? (plus advance the figure counter? Anything else to take care of?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
% lofprob2.tex SE 517383  page range

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\addtolof}[3]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{\numberline{#1}#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\addtolof{5}{My image sequence}{50-53}

\end{document}
```

where `\addtolof{<figure number>}{<figure caption/title>}{<page range>}` is what I think you want (this could be generalised to tables, etc. with an extra argument to a revised `\addto...` macro). However you might need to adjust the amount of space for page numbers in the LoF (obviously a page range takes more space than a single page number). The `tocloft` package (`> texdoc tocloft`) can help you with this, but it is up to you.

Comment: I enhanced this to `\newcommand*{\addtolofsequencebylabels}[3]{{ \stepcounter{figure}\ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#2}}{\pageref{#3}}}{\def\pagerange{\pageref{#2}}}{\def\pagerange{\pageref{#2}--\pageref{#3}}}
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}#1}{\pagerange}}}}` and then `\addtolofsequencebylabels{<figure caption>}{<label of first img>}{<label of last img>}` seems to do all I want. (My tests seem to behave oddly only with weird mixtures of float and non-float images without intermediate content - but that should not occur irl)